# Installing Perl on Windows Vista

Tags: perl

I need to run perl on  my windows vista machine. I downloaded the 64 bit version of 'active perl' (because I have a 64 bit machine) from here: http://www.perl.org/get.html#win32 
(ActivePerl-5.14.2.1402-MSWin32-x64-295342.msi)

I ran the executable and just followed the default prompts.

After installing, I typed into my cmd prompt:

```
perl -v
```

...and it spit out...

```
'perl' is not recognized as an internal or operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: This is probably a better question for SuperUser or Server Fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [PATH](http://banagale.com/changing-your-system-path-in-windows-vista.htm) is probably not set up to point to your perl installation.

Comment: The solution might be as simple as typing `perl` in a *new* command prompt.

Comment: Thanks. That was it.  (I also had to restart)

Comment: always restart a windows box, after you do anything, ever

Comment: @Joel Berger, nah, just had to restart the console. Like in unix, the environment is passed down from parent to child.